# I broke database after reuploading local version - what exactly happened? Database error

Tags: database, errors, import, export

The site was already working but since I wanted to change the website more and my Internet is not good right now, I decided to download the whole wp folder to local drive, and export database. I set up xampp, all went well. Then I was editing and I put it back like this: 1) first I renamed the wp folder to wp_old, and uploaded the new one; 2) then I tried to import the db in phpmyadmin but it didn't let me (something something already exists) - so I renamed the old DB to db_old and imported the new one. I changed the values that referred to 127.0.0.1 to mywebsite.com (home and url)
but now if I go to website:
Error establishing a database connection
and wp-admin gives me:
Can’t select database We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the ****_* database.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance for any feedback I will be really grateful if you take the time to help me
In phpmyadmin the situation looks strange ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhlV1.png - why do the dbs "stack" like that?

Comment: did you update wp-config.php to point to new database since you renamed it?

Comment: You DB name is wrong. Don't worry about thr "stacking". PhpMyAdmin groups by prefix. It has nothing to do with the functioning of the databases.

Comment: But even if I rename from ***_wp272_new to ***_wp272 the error persists

Comment: As far as I can tell the name in the phpmyadmin and the wp-config.php are exactly the same

Comment: Another strange thing in phpmyadmin is how it displays my databases it doesnt show all the tabs http://i.imgur.com/C9Fvv4H.png